# json() не может получить одну цифру

Tags: python, json

сделал скрипт, который получает все паблики вк, где я администратор, и их нужно отсортировать по подписчикам

```
f = requests.get("https://api.vk.com/method/groups.get?access_token=" + token + "&extended=1&filter=admin,editor,moder&fields=members_count&v=5.131")
for i in range(f.json()["response"]["count"]):
    if f.json()["response"]["items"][i]["members_count"] >= 27:
            print(f.json()["response"]["items"][i]["members_count"], f.json()["response"]["items"][i]["name"])
```

но он выводит всё, кроме одной группы и выдает ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в чём может быть дело? спасибо!

Comment: Ответ, который вы получаете не содержит данного ключа.

Comment: Ну посмотрите что у вас там в `json` и нам покажите, если сами не можете разобраться

Comment: Сделайте `print(f.json()["response"]["items"][i])` и посмотрите, что там. Может там пустой словарь вообще, или просто ключа такого нет, такие случаи нужно будет обрабатывать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

дело было в том, что одна из групп заблокирована, а у блокированных групп members_count не выводится